# Using Boto to automate upload to AWS S3 bucket Yields Expired Token Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Very new to AWS.  I'm trying to upload a directory of files to AWS using python and Boto3

I have used terminal to set the various tokens provided from the console and then can use
AWS command line to successfully transfer a file to my bucket using the command:

`> aws s3 cp C://dog.jpg s3://mybucketname/dog.jpg`

Now I want to automate a whole slew of files, so I run the following code in python 3.7

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = "provided access key id"
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = "provided secret access key"
os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = "provided session token"

#create the client
s3 = boto3.client(
's3',
region_name = 'ca-central-1',
aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
aws_session_token=os.environ.get('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'),
)

def upload_file(s3_client, file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket
    :param s3_client: client to upload with
    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    #try the upload
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True

upload_file(s3,'c:\\dog.jpg','mys3bucket','doggy.jpg')
```

I get the following error

> An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token has expired.

I've used the exact same keys/credentials as moments before.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` - This is only needed when you are using temporary credentials.

Can you make sure you are using temporary credentials ? Like you are assuming a role or you are doing a web identity federation.

If not, Please remove it from your code

```
s3 = boto3.client(
  's3',
  region_name = 'ca-central-1',
  aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
  aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues few months back. I solved it via following method.

One easy hack for this is to write the files in a temp folder. And then use os python library to execute "aws s3 cp recursive" command in your script to upload it to S3.

Comment: I tried this by using aws s3 sync using subprocess to launch from the shell and received an error "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records".  However using the awscli and the sync command I am able to sync a whole directory, so not sure why it's not recognizing my tokens here.  I think it might be something wrong with my environmental variables?

Comment: Seems like a env variable issue in that case. Well, Do my approach helped you solve the issue?

Comment: no.  I run python using anaconda.  When I use the anaconda terminal to input my credentials and then type ```aws s3 ls``` it works.   When I open vs code and input my credentials to the terminal there and type the same code I get the invalid access key.  Any script in which I use a subprocess call to access the awscli returns this error.

Comment: why you are using the subprocess for that. You can do that same(main) process

Comment: My thought was to use subprocess to execute a shell command